# zoom out a photo without using pinch/UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image-processing, crop

I'm making a process on a certain part of an image, I'm using the following code but the image retrieved on imageToDoProce is always zoomed in, My app will get complete if I could zoom out this photo.
This photo is not viewed to the user, hence I don't want to use Pinch/UIScrollView.
I just need a method to zoom out the photo or someone guide me to the mistake in my code that let the photo zoomed in.
Thanks

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    [connection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer); 
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0); 
    uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer); 
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer); 
    size_t width= CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height=CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);



    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); 
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, 640, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,200,320,48);

    CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *imageRef= [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(newImage, rect) scale:1 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);



    UIImage *imageToDoProce = imageRef;

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 48)]; // frame is a CGRect.
    imageView.image = imageToDoProce;




   // UIImage* croppedImage = [CameraImageHelper croppedImageWithImage:imageView.image zoom:2];


   NSString*ret= [self DoProcess:imageView.image];
    //NSLog(@"obj=%@",[CameraImageHelper getSendResult]);
    NSLog(@"rec=%@",ret);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[CameraImageHelper getSendResult].res1 setText:ret];
        [[CameraImageHelper getSendResult].image123 setImage:imageToDoProce] ;
    });    
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have developed few camera apps and they are in the app store. I can help you on this. But I want to know what is the size of the required image.

Comment: Thanks for posting, Here is the size that u,ve asked for (0,200,320,48)

Comment: one thing, the ratio of the image returned to this method is 3:4 . Therefore if we scale the image, we should keep the ratio as it is. Just think you have a image of size (320,430). Then what is the rect you want to crop ? what area you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set content mode to image123 at your "CameraImageHelper" class

```
[image123 setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: @ Augustine P A 
Thanks for posting, But unfortunately this post didn't solve my problem

Comment: With making some modifications over my image, and using ur code, It has been solved. So many thanks.